# Current and Heat in Circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

[image]

Find current through the circuit. Also, find heat generated in each resistor.

***MY ANSWER:-***

**In Parallel,**

**1/R<sub>p</sub> = 1/12 + 1/6 = (1+2)/12 = 4/12**

**R<sub>p</sub>=3 ohm**

**Total Resistance = 4 + 4 ohms = 8 ohms**

**Current, I = V/R = 16/8 = 2A**

**Total Heat:- H= I<sup>2</sup>Rt**

**H = 2<sup>2</sup> x 8 x (1 second) = 4 x 8 = 32 J**

I know for total heat, but how to find heat in individual resistor?

Comment: Hi Harshan01. Welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see this Meta post on asking homework questions and this Meta post for "check my work"  problems at http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic

Comment: This is 100 % pure homework, at least show us *some* attempt at working out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overall resistance of the circuit is 8 ohms.
$$
I = \frac{V}{R} \\
I = \frac{16}{8} \\
I = 2 \textrm{ A}$$

2 A will flow through the first four ohm resistor, 1.33 A through the 12 ohm and 0.67 A through the 6 ohm resistor. You can now calculate the power dissipated in each resistor by using $P=I^2R$.

Comment: But Heat energy is H=I<sup>2</sup>Rt , right?

Comment: @Harshan01 Yes. But then you'd need to know the amount of time that the circuit was left switched on for, and you didn't provide this.

Comment: Yes, I understand. 1 second of energy is equal to power, right?

Comment: @Harshan01 "1 second of energy is equal to power" is totally meaningless. They are entirely different concepts.

Comment: I mean in this case, if you take time as 1 second, you still arrive at same results.

Comment: H=(I^2)Rt, But if, time = 1 second, H=(I^2)R=P.

Comment: But I found out that 1 second of energy has same integer value as power. In this case, I'm mostly concerned about integer values.